# Do I need an ADSL faceplate if I am not using my phone line?

Tags: socket, telephone, phone-wiring

I have a bulky ADSL faceplate on my phone socket, and it's taking a lot of room, so I can't put furniture in from of it.

I don't use my phone line, so I was wondering if I could use a slim standard faceplate with no filter inside and still be able to connect to the Internet?

Comment: if you are not using the jack for voice, then you can remove the bulky filter .... the filter blocks the sound of the ADSL signal, so that you do not hear it when you are using the phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DSL filters are used to prevent voice communications from affecting the DSL (data) signal and vice versa. Typical home phone wiring is a combination of tree (each jack connecting separately back to the network interface (that's phone company terminology for the "main connection", NOT necessarily anything to do with your computer network per se) and daisy-chain (cable from network interface to one jack and then another cable from that jack to the next jack). Bottom line: DSL handles open jacks (no devices connected) just fine and **only** needs filters on the jacks connected to telephones, answering machines, fax machines, etc. Never put a filter on the DSL modem  itself - the DSL modem includes a different type of filter internally.

I typically wire up a filter at the network interface, after splitting to a separate cable for the DSL modem, but most people don't do that. End result: put filters where you need them and not where you don't. If you ever connect a phone again at that location then you can either put the DSL wall-plate/jack back in or use a regular inline DSL filter. If you were to ever connect a phone without (re)installing a filter, there would be no damage, but your DSL connection would be degraded (slower or not work at all) until you install a filter or disconnect the phone.